Is there a list of UPS API oauth scopes?
Is there a list of oauth scopes used in the UPS API?
Ideally I'm looking for one not requiring access to a configured "app" as I am unable to create one at this time.
Alternatively, where would I find this in the API reference page?
Currently, I'm looking at the security section of each entry, and wildly guessing that, for example, the rating endpoint requires Rate_oauth2 and the token generation endpoint requires API_basicAuth. BUT I have no idea if this is correct.
Thank you!

i believe you need an app to generate the oauth tokens since you need to pass in a client_id and secret.
here is where you can find out how to set up your app and get client_id/secret:
https://developer.ups.com/get-started?loc=en_US
and here is the flow how to get auth tokens:
https://developer.ups.com/api/reference/oauth/authorization-code?loc=en_US
the only value for {scope} i saw was 'read' and that worked for my uses (getting rates but not purchasing any labels)
